# Force row height in HTML for ng-animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS module with a page that shows a table of topics and subtopics. Each topic is a tbody element with 2 rows: one representing the topic name, and one containing a nested table where the rows are the subtopics. Each topic has an expand / collapse button that controls the subtopics, i.e. ng-shows / hides the row where the subtopics table is:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="topic in topics">
        <tr>
            <td>{{topic.name}}</td>
            <td class="toggle-subtopics" ng-click="toggleSubtopics(topic)"><a href="#">Expand / collapse</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="test-height" ng-show="topic.expanded">
            <td colspan=2>
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="subtopic in topic.subtopics">
                        <td>{{subtopic.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like the subtopics row to appear / disappear with `ng-animation`, but the main problem is that no matter what I do, I can't seem to control the height of this row.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KF6n8/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to control a td height you need to work on the line-height instead of height

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KF6n8/4/)

Code Snippet:

```
.test-height {
    line-height: 40px !important; /* This doesn't affect the height of the row */
}
```

Option 1:

Updated Code:

```
.table > tbody > tr >td {
    line-height: 40px !important;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle Option 1](http://jsfiddle.net/KF6n8/7/)

Option 2:

If you do not want to mess with bootstrap global space you can create your own class and assign that to individual td

Updated Code:

```
.fixed-height {
    line-height: 40px !important;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle Option 2](http://jsfiddle.net/KF6n8/8/)

Comment: Thanks, it does solve the problem for the fiddle. Unfortunately it's a simplified version of my real code, for which this solution doesn't work. The real inner has a bootstrap table that contains various columns with spans and elements (among others, bootstrap glyphicons). For some reason, line-height doesn't affect it at all.

Comment: Try to append !important to the line height. Bootstrap has its own line height which might be conflicting. You can also recreate the element in css to avoid defaults

Comment: Unfortunately !important doesn't seem to fix it. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/KF6n8/6/

Comment: Hi Updated the code and the fiddle please find that in the answer. Gave two options

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.test-height {
    height: 3px; 

   overflow:hidden;
   display:block;

}
```

Comment: That seems to control the height of the table inside the row, but not the height of the row itself. Oddly, it also affects the row above it: http://jsfiddle.net/KF6n8/3/